# Bash regular expression with quotes

Tags: regex, bash

I am writing a script and I want to check a variable for a format. This is the function I use :

```
check_non_numeric() {
    #re='^\".*\"$'
    re='\[^\]*\'
    if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
        echo "'$1' is not a valid format - \"[name]\" "
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

I want the regular expression to match a string with anything but quotation mark inside and quotation marks around it ("a" or "string" or "dsfo!^$**#"). The problem is that these regular expressions that I came up with dont work for me. I have used a very similar function to check if a variable is an integer or float and it worked there. Could you please tell me what the regular expression in question should be ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try `re='^[^"]*$'`

Comment: this accepts everything

Comment: I am confused about what you want. Do you want quotes surrounding the string but not inside it? Or do you not want any quotes at all?

Comment: Not going to edit, but I believe you meant "string inside, with quotations marks around it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant you want to match anything that is not a string surrounded by quotes.  It's easier to match use your regex to match, and the bash-test to "not" match it-- if that's not clear, use `!`. Here's a couple of ways to do it.

`if [[ ! $(expr "$string" : '\".*\"') -gt 0 ]]; then echo "expr good"; fi`

`if [[ ! "$string" =~ \".*\" ]]; then echo "test good"; fi`

Make sure you quote your variable you are testing with expr (which is there for edification purposes only).

Answer (score 1):

As you want to match anything except string with quotation marks, you just target the quotation mark:

```
re='["]'
if [[ ! $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
```

Actually you don't need regex for this. Globbing will be enough:

```
if [[ ! $1 = *\"* ]]; then
...
fi
```

Comment: I maybe know why - I get the name with "while getopts" loop and I use it like "check_non_numeric "$OPTARG", but when I try to echo it in the function, it shows without them - I will try to find how to preserve them in variables

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is very, very far off. `\[` matches a literal left square bracket, and `^` (outside a character class) matches beginning of line.

Something like `'^"[^"]*"'` should work, if that's really what you want.

However, I kind of doubt that. In order to pass a value in literal double quotes, you would need something like

```
yourprogram '"value"'
```

or

```
yourprogram "\"value\""
```

which I would certainly want to avoid if I were you.

Comment: He'd not need `yourprogram '"value"'` if he wasn't passing the string as an argument to the script, but reading it as a line from a file-- which I'm almost certain is the case.